# Light confinement in homojunction laser diode

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser, laser-cavity

Why is light confined to the depletion region in a simple homojunction Fabry-Perot laser diode, like the one schematically illustrated below? Does this region for some reason have a higher refractive index even though, it too, is GaAs? If so, Why? I cannot find anything on this. Thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In laser diodes there are basically two ways of optical confinement

- index guiding

  There the laser has a refractive index profile and the optical wave is confined because of this. This may be because the refractive index of the active region is different  and/or because there is a ridge for the other lateral dimension.
- gain guiding

  Here it is used that the gain is inhomgeneous and the light wave is only amplified there. This does not remove scattering/diffraction, but the gain might be high enough to achieve lasing. Due to Kramers Kronig this may go along with some index guiding as well (because if there is gain, there is also a refractive index change even if it is the same material).

Modern laser diodes are mostly index guided.

Comment: So, if the active region of the device pictured was just the depletion region of a GaAs p-n junction, the pictured device would not actually work? Even in the ideal case?

Comment: I am sure it can work and think the first semiconductor laser was of this kind. Quantum well lasers were invented later.

Comment: Why is light confined in the depletion region of such a device?